# ngStorage not storing data when being updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

I am building a directive that handles out courses, part of this is saving course data in local storage so the user can resume.

When the data changes i call this function

```
function setLocalStorage(){
    if(!preview){
        $localStorage.scorm = scope.scorm
    }
}
```

I also call is when they first load up the course

My problem is that the data is not updated in local storage.

When i debug i can see that `$localstorage.scorm` is getting updated in chrome console but the data in the actual local storage is unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using $apply

```
function setLocalStorage(){
    if(!preview){
        scope.$apply(function () {
            $localStorage.scorm = scope.scorm;
        });
    }
}
```